# Force pyspark to write string data type to CSV

Tags: pyspark

While writing a pyspark dataframe to csv, it is converting a column which has numerical values but are represented in form of string because of preceding zeroes for eg: 00,01 and so on.. But while writing it to csv these values become 0,1 and so on..
How can I prevent this?

Current code to csv:

Using jupyter notebook:

```
%%time
data.write.mode(“overwrite”).csv(“path to file”, header= True)
```

And

```
data.printSchema()
```

Gives output as:
col_name: string (nullable= true)

The data is fetched using sql queries

Comment: if you're opening the csv on excel, it is excel that removes the leading zeroes and coerces it to integers. try by force adding quotes around all values. see `quoteAll` option.

Comment: But when I again read csv file in python the values still remain the same I.e those strings are Converted to integer type. @samkart

Comment: @Rsha can you show us your sample data?